# Ever-present stubborn subpage in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Okay, so I am at my whit's end with an issue.

I am working with an application that is mostly jQuery Mobile and Javascript, with some jQuery for dynamically creating HTML.

We are using a jQuery plug-in for creating a subpage, which works fine.  The subpage renders just fine, but it gives me a very stubborn issue after navigating back to the original page.  Once back on the actual page, I am left with a 15 pixel margin on the bottom, which is apparently the content div of the subpage, which has been destroyed and left empty and unpopulated, but apparently pinned to the bottom of my page.  The header and footer divs don't show up, just the padding of the content div.

I've tried manipulating the height, padding, and display css with jQuery, all which either do nothing or hide the entire age, not just the subpage div or subpage content div.  I have the same problems with $('div').hide(), $('div').remove, and other such jQuery methods, all which turn the entire original page blank in the process.

Any pointers?

Comment: Without more of your coding to represent whats actually happening when where how.. trying to help you is going to be tough. As there are literally thousands of ways to do any given thing. You could be adding/removing classes, you could by dynamically manipulating the elements height and with through JS, or whatever the case. But in any case there are to many questions to be asked of how your doing whatever it is your doing, and without answers to those, no guidance can be provided.

Comment: Also for reference, jQuery/jQuery Mobile are essentially the same thing one is just basically a stripped down version of the other. That and both are JavaScript. Javascript isn't some independent thing. jQuery is a library or framework (how ever you'd like to word it) That makes things easier in some aspects while working with javascript. But in all is written in JavaScript